# Performing DML on records who have inactive owners

Tags: apex, visualforce, customer-portal, user

I have a Quote__C(custom Object) whose owner is a portal user which is now inactive. I have to perform a dml on such record ,but salesforce isnt allowing me to do so(from other portal user profile with whom record is shared). Any help how to do will be appreciated.

Comment: Previously, only administrators were able to edit accounts, opportunities, and custom object records that are owned by inactive users. With Spring ’15, administrators and all users with the create or edit permission can create or edit accounts, opportunities, and custom object records that are owned by inactive users. For example, you can edit the Account Name field on an opportunity record that is owned by an inactive user.

Comment: Which user is triggering the DML?

Comment: Portal User, not salesforce platform user.

Comment: You will have to take the ownership of those records and then perform DML.

Comment: Whats the use of this then?
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sharing_inactive_users.htm

Comment: Not that useful. I only posted to be helpful as I wasn't sure of your use case

Comment: You probably need to back off the update to batch or future job which runs not as the portal user